# How do I use an ObservableList with a ListView?

Tags: java, javafx

I have been fairly unsuccessful with implementing the simplest of ListView even after reading all the ListView documentation at Oracle. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ListView.html

How do I get my `ListView processingListView` to automatically reflect the contents of my  `ObservableList processingList`? It seems that the ListView completely ignores my provided ObservableList and instead uses some empty list that can only be accessed through the `getItems` method. Please view comments in code below for further details.

```
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.stage.FileChooser;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.List;

public class MainController {
    @FXML
    private Button addItemsToProcListButton;

    private ObservableList<File> processingList = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
            new File("/Users/matt/Dropbox/Matthew/chart.png") // Example file doesn't show up when loaded
    );

    @FXML
    private ListView<File> processingListView = new ListView<>(processingList);

    @FXML
    private void addItemsToProcessingList() {
        final Stage stage = (Stage) addItemsToProcListButton.getScene().getWindow();
        final FileChooser fileChooser = new FileChooser();

        fileChooser.setTitle("Add Images to Processing List");
        fileChooser.getExtensionFilters().addAll(
            new FileChooser.ExtensionFilter("Image Files", "*.png", "*.jpg", "*.gif")
        );

        App.logger.info("processingList size = " + processingList.size()); // Shows expected size
        App.logger.info("listViewList size = " + processingListView.getItems().size()); // Always 0

        List<File> files = fileChooser.showOpenMultipleDialog(stage);
        processingList.addAll(files);

        App.logger.info("processingList size = " + processingList.size()); // Increases as expected
        App.logger.info("listViewList size = " + processingListView.getItems().size()); // Always 0

        // I can see items if I manually add them but this doesn't follow the suggested pattern
        // processingListView.setItems(processingList);

        // Updates but is not recommended https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/control/ListView.html
        // processingListView.getItems().addAll(files);
    }
}
```

### Updated Solution

I was erroneously creating new objects for my ObservableList and ListView inside my controller when I should have used the appropriate markup inside my FXML file.

I changed my class to the following

```
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.stage.FileChooser;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.List;

public class MainController {
    @FXML
    private Button addItemsToProcListButton;

    @FXML
    private ObservableList<File> processingList;

    @FXML
    private ListView<File> processingListView;

    @FXML
    private void addItemsToProcessingList() {
        final Stage stage = (Stage) addItemsToProcListButton.getScene().getWindow();
        final FileChooser fileChooser = new FileChooser();

        fileChooser.setTitle("Add Images to Processing List");
        fileChooser.getExtensionFilters().addAll(
            new FileChooser.ExtensionFilter("Image Files", "*.png", "*.jpg", "*.gif")
        );

        final List<File> files = fileChooser.showOpenMultipleDialog(stage);
        processingList.addAll(files);
    }
}
```

I changed my previous FXML file

```
<ListView prefWidth="300.0" fx:id="processingListView" />
```

to

```
<ListView prefWidth="300.0" fx:id="processingListView">
    <items>
        <FXCollections fx:factory="observableArrayList" fx:id="processingList"></FXCollections>
    </items>
</ListView>
```

Comment: If this is a controller for an FXML file, the list view is created in the FXML. Don't create a new list view in the controller.

Comment: James_D yes this is a controller for an FXML file. I will play around with your suggestion to see if that helps

Comment: Seems like I got it to work based on your input. I was doing exactly what you said and I also wasn't creating the collection in my FXML file.

Comment: I will accept an answer if you post one James. Thank you